# Multiple custom grok patterns not matching, but they successfully match alone?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

Grok matches single custom patterns, but does match when custom patterns are combined.

**Complete, working, an verifiable example**

Sample data:

```
OK 05/20 20:12:10:067 ABC_02~~DE_02 FGH_IJK jsmith _A0011
```

Custom patterns:

```
MMDD [0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]
THREAD _A\w+
```

They work separately; specifically, this pattern works by itself:

```
%{MMDD:mmdd} 

// Result
{
  "mmdd": [
    [
      "05/20"
    ]
  ]
}
```

... and this pattern works by itself:

```
%{THREAD:thread}

// Result
{
  "thread": [
    [
      "_A0011"
    ]
  ]
}
```

..but together, they fail:

```
%{MMDD:mmdd} %{THREAD:keyword}

No Matches
```

Puzzling. Tyvm Keith :^)

Testing here:
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Regex Resource:
https://regex101.com/

**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

**EDIT based on Jeff Y's comment below**

Note change of `keyword` to `thread`

```
// Grok Pattern
%{MMDD:mmdd}%{DATA}%{THREAD:thread}

// Result
{
  "mmdd": [
    [
      "05/20"
    ]
  ],
  "DATA": [
    [
      " 20:12:10:067 ABC_02~~DE_02 FGH_IJK jsmith "
    ]
  ],
  "thread": [
    [
      "_A0011"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

**EDIT 2 based on Jeff Y's second comment below**

```
// Data - HACKED - Note move of _A0011 to after mm/dd
OK 05/20 _A0011 20:12:10:067 ABC_02~~DE_02 FGH_IJK jsmith 

// Grok Pattern
%{MMDD:mmdd} %{THREAD:thread}

// Result
{
  "mmdd": [
    [
      "05/20"
    ]
  ],
  "thread": [
    [
      "_A0011"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking that the whole line (the together line) is considered as a pattern, and the elements you're trying to match have more than just that space, " ", between them in the data. Maybe try `%{MMDD:mmdd}%{DATA}%{THREAD:keyword}`?

Comment: @JeffY See edit above. Weird how this is not an issue with a query which uses standard patterns, which parse fine, like so: ``%{WORD:word} %{TIME:time}``

Comment: It's trying to match the whole line, including that space, to the sample data. It would work if there were exactly a single space between your thread and your mmdd fields in the data. If there is something else in between them, you have to account for it. `%{DATA}` is a builtin (core) pattern that says basically "match anything". https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Comment: @JeffY See edit 2 above. It does match when I hack the data and move the thread name ``_A0011`` next to the mm/dd ``05/20``.

Comment: After noodling on this a bit, perhaps these Grok debuggers are designed to debug exactly one Grok pattern, prior to insertion somewhere else, which is capable of applying multiple patterns. They're not intended to parse multiple patterns on one line.

Comment: @JeffY Thx again. I can leverage this to test a sequence of regex patterns. upvote upvote upvote...

Answer (score 1):

Grok will test your patterns against the whole message.

If your message is `OK 05/20 _A0011 20:12:10:067 ABC_02~~DE_02 FGH_IJK jsmith` and you only want the `05/20` and `_A0011` part, your grok should have patterns to match the rest of string, but do not save them in a field.

For example, the pattern `%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{MMDD:mmdd}%{SPACE}%{THREAD:thread}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}` will match your string, it will save the `mmdd` and `thread` fiealds, but ignore everything else.